# What means terminal prompts disabled?

Tags: gitlab, php-deployer

I use gitlab since some years.
After an update of my mac book, one application fails on deploy with deployer.

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'http://mygitlab.org:22': terminal prompts disabled
```

I use the same gitlab server for all projects. The other projects are working well.

I compared the gig config file. No differences between the applications.

I tried to set/change the username. No success

I created a new repo on gitlab, and cloned it into my php storm. No success

Has someone an idea, where i have to search?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check the URL of that repository. A port 22 is the default one used by SSH, so seeing an HTTP URL used is strange, and would trigger a prompt for the username.

This differs from a `git@mygitlab.org:` URL (or `ssh://git@mygitlab.org:22/...`), which should not need any prompt, if the right SSH key is used (and has no passphrase, or if the passphrase is cached in an ssh-agent).